# Python connect to JDBC thin custom url Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc, cx-oracle

I have a Oracle DB. The database can only be connected trough a custom jdbc URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port/service_name. Where the driver = 'Oracle in OraClient12Home_x64_1'

now I need to connect to the DB using python.

I have tried pyodbc and cx_oracle, none seems to work.

Here is what ive tried:

**pyodbc**:

```
dbq = servername:port/service_name

conn_string = fr'DRIVER={driver};DBQ={dbq};UID={uid};PWD={pwd};

connection = pyodbc.connect(dsn)
```

**cx_Oracle**:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('@servername','port',service_name='service_name')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn)
```

I continue to get TNS: identifier error or TNS Adapter error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the cx_Oracle doc on mapping from JDBC connection strings: [JDBC and Oracle SQL Developer Connection Strings](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#jdbc-and-oracle-sql-developer-connection-strings)

Try without the '@' you showed:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('example.com','1521',service_name='mydbservice')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn)
```

Substitute your actual values

or simply use

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, 'example.com:1521/mydbservice')
```